# Changing tick labels in python pptx

Tags: python, python-pptx

I don't know how to change the tick label text of category axis. I want to extract these texts and insert with another. So, if someone help me how can I do with this case, please!

```
from pptx.enum.chart import XL_CHART_TYPE
from pptx import Presentation
proj1 = Presentation("C:/Users/naych/Documents/chart.pptx")
for slide in proj1.slides:
    for shape in slide.shapes:
        if shape.has_chart:
            chart=shape.chart
           
            if chart.chart_title.has_text_frame:
                print(chart.chart_title.text_frame.text)
                category_axis=chart.category_axis
                category_axis.tick_labels.font.italic=True
                           
proj1.save('new_chart_lang.pptx')
```

and I got this output.
Snow falling

In my slide, there are only one bar chart. There are one chart title, 'Snow falling' and four category axis labels. I wanna to get these category axis labels. I hope someone can help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can "get" (read) the category labels like this:

```
for category in chart.plots[0].categories:
    print(category.label)
```

To change them, you need to rewrite the `ChartData` for the chart, because these names are actually stored in the embedded Excel worksheet that provides the chart's data. That is accomplished using the `Chart.replace_data()` method.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Nay :)  Don't neglect to accept the answer that resolves your question. You do that by clicking the checkmark next to the number at the left of the response :)

Comment: Hello scanny, when I am using Chart.replace_data() method, I meet with Chart Repair error and can you help me how can I fix this error, please!

Comment: @Nay post a separate question, show the code you're using and describe the results. Make sure to use the `python-pptx` tag and I'll take a look.